# Encrypt Javascript - Decrypt Java

Tags: javascript, java

I want to encrypt the password before to submit.

app.js

```js
function encryptPass() {
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Test", "1234").toString();
    $("#password").val(encrypted)
}
```

After to submit, the tool call method: decrypt

pass.java

```java
public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt) {
    def result

    try {
        if (strToDecrypt) {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, obtenerSecretKey());

            result = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt)))
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        println e
        throw e;
    } finally {
        return result
    }
}

private static SecretKeySpec obtenerSecretKey () {
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    def semilla = "1234"

    def key = sha.digest(semilla.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);

    return new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
}
```

I'm getting this error:

`javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.`

Any suggestions or other encrypt type?

Comment: There is no reason to do that. Your password submission should be over HTTPS, which is already an encrypted connection.

Comment: I worked on a project that used `bcrypt` to encrypt a pswd to store on DB. Later on, another part of this project needed to allow password change using Spring. I managed to check for password match and store new password in Java importing `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder`.
Password check passed in either side of the project

Comment: @Pointy I'm using HTTPS but when I intercept the request I can see the passwin in text plain. Exmaple : do=login&forceredirect=1&url=%2F&vb_login_md5password=&vb_login_md5password_utf=&s=&securitytoken=guest&vb_login_username=testing&vb_login_password=password_plain

Comment: @estefaniaVG what's important is that the password is encrypted in transit from the browser, across the Internet, and to your server. Inside your server, it will be plain text, but your code will immediately hash it with a secure hash and store it in the database.

Comment: @Pointy This is in login view, if someone intercept the request, he have the credentials(user/pass)

Comment: Not if your login page is an https page

Comment: If you use https correctly, the request cannot be intercepted.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is harmful to do what the question asks.

Comment: @Pointy Please any url to explain with https is enough

Comment: Even if you do encrypt the password, the key to decrypt it is available at client side (browser's javascript) so the interceptor can get it and decrypt the password. I agree that httpS should be enough. You can also explore [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) for added protection.